# ArcGIS script for mapping lat/long coordinates to boxes/rectangles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Working on a project that requires me to take lat/long coordinates and map them as rectanglular boxes on ArcMap 10.1. To be clear, the upper left & lower right corners of each box/rectangle are determined by two sets of lat/long coordinates, that have been compiled as pairs in the following format in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
Upper Left X/Y | Lower Right X/Y
--------------------------------
(XX.X, -YY.Y)  | (XX.X, -YY.Y)
```

(so "(XX.X,-YY.Y)" are in single cells...multi-valued entries, yes.)

I need to map them over the contiguous US, so I'll be using NAD 83 as my spatial reference. All the resulting box/rectangle features should be saved into one polygon Shapefile.

My question is, how do I go about *automating* this whole process with a Python/ArcPy script, or via some other method? I know this should be simple, but I don't know a single thing about Python, and need to replicate this process for hundreds of boxes.

Comment: Is this a continuous grid of cells of the same size or are these cells of random size and in random locations?